# Bokeh custom ToolTips {safe} tag displays nothing

Tags: javascript, python, plot, tooltip, bokeh

When running the following [Bokeh code](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip), using the latest Bokeh and py35, the `@fonts{safe}` does not show up at all in the ToolTip. However when `{safe}` is deleted `@fonts` appears (not rendered of course). Does anyone know what I can do to make `{safe}` work? Or is there another way that I could make HTML render in ToolTips?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(
            x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
            desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
            imgs = [
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
            ],
            fonts=['<i>italics</i>',
                   '<pre>pre</pre>',
                   '<b>bold</b>',
                   '<small>small</small>',
                   '<del>del</del>'
                   ]
        )
    )

hover = HoverTool(
        tooltips="""
        <div>
            <div>
                <img
                    src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                    style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                    border="2"
                ></img>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@desc</span>
                <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">[$index]</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>@fonts{safe}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 15px;">Location</span>
                <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        """
    )

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=[hover],
           title="Mouse over the dots")

p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was [a bug in the code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5460#issuecomment-271875891). I made the changes suggested [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5460#issuecomment-271893036) and created this [pull request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5700). As of 1/11/2017 the fix will not be install able through pip but if you follow [@bryevdv's advice](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5460#issuecomment-271904131) you can install it through [conda developer channel](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/installation.html#developer-builds) or build it from scratch like I did through the [dev guide](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/dev_guide/setup.html#building-bokehjs).