# Custom template for HTMLTemplateFormatter with CSS styling for Bokeh DataTable

Tags: python, css, bokeh

I am trying to set up a small Bokeh app with a DataTable that might contain long text depending on columns. I would like to have a nice tooltip tool to display the full truncated text while moving the mouse above the corresponding cell.

I went through a previous question that might perfectly do the job but I am unable to get the correct result. 
Here is the previous question : [How to add HoverTool to a Data Table (Bokeh, Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169264/how-to-add-hovertool-to-a-data-table-bokeh-python)

The solution I am investigating is the one provided by Ferrard with nice CSS styling.

Unfortunalety I know almost nothing about CSS and html.

Here are the code I am trying to reproduce.

**main.py**

```py
main.py:

from os.path import dirname, join
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Div
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter
from bokeh.layouts import layout

template = """<div class="tooltip-parent"><div class="tooltipped"><%= value %></div><div class="tooltip-text"><%= value %></div></div>"""

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['this is a longer text that needs a tooltip, because otherwise we do not see the whole text', 'this is a short text'],
    ['this is another loooooooooooooooong text that needs a tooltip', 'not much here'],
], columns=['a', 'b'])

columns = [TableColumn(field=c, title=c, width=20, formatter=HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template)) for c in ['a', 'b']]

table = DataTable(source=ColumnDataSource(df), columns=columns)

l = layout([[table]])

curdoc().add_root(l)

show(l)
```

**desc.html**

```html
<style>
.tooltip-parent {
    width: 100%;
}

.tooltipped {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.tooltip-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    white-space: initial;
    text-align: left;
}

.tooltipped:hover + .tooltip-text {
    visibility: visible;
}

div.bk-slick-cell {
    overflow: visible !important;
    z-index: auto !important;
}
</style>

<h1>Tooltip demo</h1>
```

This is stupid but I really don't know where I should put the desc.html file in my working dir so the bokeh server can call it... I read through bokeh documentation and pay attention to Directory format for bokeh but did not manage to use either static or templates dir to achieve the proper result.

**Here is the final result I am trying to have**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB815.png (not enough reputation to link an image)

All I have on my side is the DataTable withouth the "Tooltip demo" header and without any tooltip working.

This is my first question on stack, hope everything is fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a directory style app, you can make a `templates/index.html` template that has this structure:

```
{% extends base %}

{% block title %}My Bokeh App{% endblock %}

{% block preamble %}
<style>
    /* your styles here */
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

The app will automatically render itself using this `index.html` which has your stylesheet included. In general, it would be good for there to be easier ways to add extra stylesheet specifications to Bokeh apps. I'd encourage you to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to start a discussion.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.

I tried what you provided for the index.html with the css styling. It's on the good way but there are still 2 issues :
- the tooltip display area is restricted to the "active" cell. https://imgur.com/DVEE3K4 (see the black hoover trapped in celle a0)
- it seems like I can't change anymore the row_height attribute for DataTable.

How can I correct these ? Also, should I edit my question for more clarity now?

Comment: Well, the question was how to inject custom CSS, which is what I answered. I don't know the answer to your follow-on questions, though. In general it is best to keep individual questions on SO as focused as possible and not meander from one step to another in one question.

Comment: Yes, I guess my question was a bit confusing ;-) Thanks for your help ! I'll follow your advice and will open a GitHub issue.