# holoviews table - adding custome tooltips

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews, panel-pyviz

Im building a dashboard using Panel, Holoviews and Bokeh.
One of the widgets in the dashboard is a table - which I create by using `hv.Table`.
This table is a part of an `interact` widget and current layout works fine.

Now I want to add tooltips to two of the colums in the table.
The tooltips should link to a url based on another columns value.
I've tried following solutions presented in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169264/how-to-add-hovertool-to-a-data-table-bokeh-python) with no success.
The problems are in the generated layout of the panel, widgets are squashed together and not visible(code throws no exceptions).
To my understanding(might be wrong), things get weird when using Bokeh's DataTable instead of holoviews's.

Any suggestions would be appreciated,

```
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
from panel.interact import interact

def get_grower_table(grower):
    grower_df = growers_dfs[grower]
    p = hv.Table(grower_df)
    return p

grower_ghs_view = interact(get_growers_table, grower=['MIAO', 'BAO'],)
dashboard = pn.Columns(pn.Row(grower_ghs_view))
```